# better drivers for RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe?

Tags: networking, network-manager

i am running ubuntu 20.04 ..i am running the generic drivers that installed for my card RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe ..seems to work ok ...but am having latency issues i was curious if there was a better driver i could use or a way to update .. i am totally new to this so please be patient . just seems like my connection isnt very consistent and i know its not the router im sure its something to do with the network card drivers ..i contemplated just buying a newer one and plugging it in usb ..but i didnt know if that would help ?

Comment: I have a pci wireless, it rarely connects, sometimes it is even not identified by the OS, it is very old, but for online games it used to give much better ping (about 25). I use a usb wifi too, the one that connects always easily and strong connection, I think it is because I can position it better thru a long usb cable, but in the past, usb wifi always gave bad ping (about 200).

Comment: So, my suggestion is, try the usb, positioning it in the best way possible to have the strongest signal, if it is not enough, try to position your computer just to test if the pci wifi works well at all, you can also try a differend wifi usb brand if nothing else helps. Also, did your pci wifi ever worked well? like in windows may be?